# Updating html from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Im trying to learn the basics with AngularJS and trying to make a text visible when a number is big enough. It looks like the more() function is only called once, when the page is displayed first time.
The lessThan3() function returns the correct value, but it doesnt work when trying ng-hide.

AngularJS

```
function ApplicationController($scope,$interval) {   
    $scope.number = 0;
    $interval(function() {
         $scope.number++;
    }, 1000);

    $scope.lessThan3 = function(){
        return ($scope.number < 3);
    }
}
```

Html

```
Number: {{ number }}
{{ lessThan3() }}
<p ng-hide="{{ lessThan3 }}">
    Less than 3
</p>
```

link to code: http://jsfiddle.net/bBaa2/71/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ApplicationController">   
    <pre>Number: {{ number }}</pre>
    <button ng-click="testTimer()">Test Timer</button>

    <p ng-show="more()">
    More than 3
    </p>

    <p ng-hide="more()">
    Less than 3
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not necessarily, if you check the funcion more is already looking for de number.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `HTML` code to: `<p ng-hide="number > 3">Less than 3</p>` or to `<p ng-hide="lessThan3()">Less than 3</p>` if you prefer to call the method

You don't need the data binding syntax when using `ng-hide`/`ng-show`/`ng-if`/ and other similar directives.

```js
function ApplicationController($scope,$interval) {
    
    $scope.number = 0;
  
    $scope.testTimer = function() {
        $interval(function() {
            $scope.number++;
        }, 1000);
    };
    $scope.lessThan3 = function(){
        return ($scope.number > 3);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="ApplicationController">   
    <pre>Number: {{ number }}</pre>
    <button ng-click="testTimer()">Test Timer</button>
    <p ng-show="lessThan3()">
    More than 3
    </p>
    <p ng-hide="lessThan3()">
    Less than 3
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just

```
<p ng-show="more()">
```

for the jsfiddle, or

```
<p ng-hide="lessThan3()">
```

for the example here.

without `{{}}`

Comment: Ah! Thx. Thought I was supposed to use {{ }} when using variables and functions

Comment: This is for interpolation as a string. This is a bit special when you bind to attributes.

Comment: @joxxe don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you like it :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect:

```
<p ng-hide="lessThan3()">
```

But be aware that I also think your logic is incorrect if I can assume what you are trying to do. You want to hide the element when `number` is greater than 3. Or at least change the message.